# Find elements of array with largest absolute value

Tags: list-manipulation, sorting, searching

I am wondering how to do in Mathematica the following:

Given as an input a large array, I want to output a list of top $n$ entries with largest absolute value + their location within the array.

To give a very simple explicit example, let us take

```
size = 3;
top = 5;
SeedRandom[1234];
H = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], {size, size, size}] + 
   I*RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], {size, size, size}];
H // MatrixForm
Abs[H] // MatrixForm
```

This produces array elements as follows:

[image]

And these correspond to the following absolute values:

[image]

So as an output I would like to get a list as follows

```
{
{2.67802 + 1.28002 I,{1,2,2}},
{-2.16128 + 0.250312 I,{3,2,1}},
{-0.907637 + 1.71577 I,{3,3,1}},
{-1.31683 - 1.21146 I,{1,2,3}},
{1.53659 + 0.686038 I,{1,2,1}}
}
```

i.e. first the array element (which has very large absolute value), followed by a coordinate of that array element.

Any ideas how to do this with a concise piece of code?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use [`SparseArray`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SparseArray) to do this:

```
sa = SparseArray[H];
With[{ord = Reverse @ Ordering[Abs @ sa["NonzeroValues"], -5]},
    Thread[{
        sa["NonzeroValues"][[ord]],
        sa["NonzeroPositions"][[ord]]
    }]
]
```

> {{2.67802 + 1.28002 I, {1, 2, 2}}, {-2.16128 + 0.250312 I, {3, 2, 
>      1}}, {-0.907637 + 1.71577 I, {3, 3, 1}}, {-1.31683 - 1.21146 I, {1, 2, 
>      3}}, {1.53659 + 0.686038 I, {1, 2, 1}}}

Comment: I guess it assumes `H` won't have any zero values. --- I guess you could use a nonnumeric default `SparseArray[H, Automatic, "NaN"]` to take care of the zero case.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

Let `h` be the OP's `H`, to avoid single capital letters:

```
ClearAll[next, arrayPos];
next[{{q_, r_}, d_}] := {QuotientRemainder[r, Times @@ Rest[d]], Rest[d]};
arrayPos[dims_][idx_] := 
  NestList[step, {{0, idx - 1}, dims}, Length[dims]][[2 ;;, 1, 1]] + 1;

arrayPos[Dimensions@h] /@
   Reverse@OrderingBy[Flatten@h, Abs, -5] //
 Transpose[{Extract[h, #], #}] &
(*
{{2.67802 + 1.28002 I, {1, 2, 2}},
 {-2.16128 + 0.250312 I, {3, 2, 1}},
 {-0.907637 + 1.71577 I, {3, 3, 1}},
 {-1.31683 - 1.21146 I, {1, 2, 3}},
 {1.53659 + 0.686038 I, {1, 2, 1}}}
*)
```

Answer (score 6):

This is shorter and maybe a bit faster than `SparseArray`:

```
Ordering[- Flatten @ Abs @ H, top] //
  Tuples[Range @ Dimensions @ H][[#]] & //
  Thread[{Extract[H, #], #}] &
```

> ```
> {
>  {2.67802 + 1.28002 I, {1, 2, 2}},
>  {-2.16128 + 0.250312 I, {3, 2, 1}},
>  {-0.907637 + 1.71577 I, {3, 3, 1}},
>  {-1.31683 - 1.21146 I, {1, 2, 3}},
>  {1.53659 + 0.686038 I, {1, 2, 1}}
> }
> ```

Answer (score 3):

Using a similar trick for getting a list of item-position pairs as @Mr.Wizard, here's a version where you first convert your entire array into the same format as you want your output to be (relying on the fact that `Tuples` gives you the indices in the same order as `Flatten` will leave them) and then use `MaximalBy` with your comparison function (`Abs` on the first element of that pair):

```
MaximalBy[
  Thread[{Flatten[H], Tuples[Range[Dimensions[H]]]}],
  Abs @* First,
  top
]
```

I'm using `Composition` (`@*`) in the function but eg `Abs[First[#]]&` would be equivalent.